# Open jQuery dialog box upon selecting a date from jQuery datepicker inline

Tags: jquery, dialog, datepicker

Presently my project page is having a jQuery datepicker inline placed on one of the section of the page. The below code is used to achieve the same.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/Calendar/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/Calendar/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Calendar/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("change", "#datepicker", function () {
    var date = $(this).val();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>

// The below section is in one of the sections
<div id="datepicker" style="font: 80% 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;"></div>
<script>
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
</script>
.
.
.
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
   <p>Adding the modal overlay screen.</p>
 </div>
```

Now I would have to show a jQuery dialog with information, when the user click's on a specific date.

Well I tried to call the dialog

```
$(document).on("change", "#datepicker", function () {
    var date = $(this).val();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

but it shows an error as Object doesn't support property or method dialog.

Could any body put me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: where is your element with the id "dialog"?

Comment: I think you're including some `Script` file multiple times.. please review once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look this fiddle to see if this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/qqabC/

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();

$("#datepicker").change(function(){
     var date = $(this).val();
    $('<div>' + date + '</div>').dialog();
});
```

Comment: If I remove this code $( "#dialog" ).dialog(); It works well with datepicker

Comment: Same error when I include dialog() 

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Comment: Make sure `<div id="dialog"> </div>` is present

Comment: Did you download the jquery using Download Builder  from the jquery website? if so did you make sure you had the dialog (in the widgets section) checkbox seleted? Just try to put a div with some id in your webpage and call $('#idofthediv').dialog(). If it gives the same error it could be becuase the jquery files downloaded is not complete.

Comment: Thank you for the help provided by all. It turned out I was using the wrong version of the Jquery. I updated to jquery-ui-1.10.2 and every thing worked.

Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Mark as answer if ur satisfied

Answer (score 0):

I think you are including `jquery` twice. You have a `jquery-1.9.1.js` and also some other `jquery-1.x.x.js` script files included, or same `jquery-1.9.1.js` 2nd time  Everything seems to be plugging into the first instance and then the last include overrides `$`. So that's why you're seeing this error message.

**Please review once again..**

also Include  `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` into your script tag to avoid conflicts!

Comment: Vitthal, I did checked every thing Jquery is only rendering in the above code no were else. And i only get the error when I include .dialog() method. the code works fine without it.

Comment: Edited the Answer.. check now adding that `noConflict();`

Comment: If I use jQuery.noConflict() it says object expected

Comment: Thank you for the help provided. It turned out I was using the wrong version of the Jquery. I updated to jquery-ui-1.10.2 and every thing worked.

Thank you again for the help.