# Using datepicker with jquery, dialog box associated with div onselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, onselect

Not sure if this is possible, I'm just starting to learn javascript and jQuery. If the way that I would like is not possible, I am very open to hearing of different ways I may be able to achieve this.

I want to display a datepicker, the user will click on dates and when they do a dialog box appears which has specific predefined data in it. They can select a different date, and it will open another dialog box with different predefined data in it, and I want to keep track of the dates that they click on.

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>I'm going to have different data applying to only this day</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>I'm going to have different data applying to only this day</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>I'm going to have different data applying to only this day</p>
</div>
</div>
```

[Open jQuery dialog box upon selecting a date from jQuery datepicker inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469553/open-jquery-dialog-box-upon-selecting-a-date-from-jquery-datepicker-inline)

That link was useful because a user has a jsfiddle posted: http://jsfiddle.net/qqabC/ which is a start to what I am trying to do, I am just not sure of how or if it is even possible to incorporate divs into the dialog boxes like so. I keep messing around with it but I have been getting nowhere. Each date that is selected will have different dialog box content in it.

If this is not possible, what would be the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

--Edit:
I still need to implement the divs that I have defined above with div id "tabs". Tabs = workout days. So tabs-1 to tabs-5 would be 5 total days. tabs-1 is going to be their first click which is day 1 form content, tabs-2 will be their second click which is day 2 form content, and so on. I believe I should use a for loop, because which each click the div is being incremented onto the next one. I was trying to do something like:

```
 var divs = $('#tabs > div[id]');
 var links = $('#tabs li');
 divs.hide();
 for (i=0;i<=max_workouts;i++) {
     $('#tabs li').on('click', function(e){
     var clickedID = $(this).attr('href').clone().appendTo(#workout-modal);
     }
```

Something like that, to iterate through the div's with each click, but it's not working, I have been trying to find examples of placing existing div content in modals but there is nothing on iterating through divs in this way, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I would use [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for something like this myself, just easier to manage IMHO

Comment: Where you wanna incorporate `divs`? into the dialogbox?

Comment: Thank you @DelightedD0D for the suggestion, that is my first time seeing bootstrap modals I will look into that it looks neat.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes I would like to incorporate the divs into the dialogbox if possible

Comment: @JaneDoe Adding html to the dialog box is possible, see https://jqueryui.com/dialog/  and click on the "view source" link, youll see the dialog html is on the page and just displayed when they call `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();`, though Id still use bootstrap if it were me. I just find it more comfortable to work with and setup how I want it. But to be fair, my projects usually use a lot of the other bootstrap features as well so it makes sense for me :)

Comment: Something **[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qqabC/33/)**?

Comment: @JaneDoe when you say "Each date that is selected will have different dialog box content in it." can you elaborate on that? WEe might be able to greatly simplify the logic if we understand that a bit better

Comment: And there is **[some other way too](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qqabC/34/)**.. In fact there are many ways to integrate.. :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D In regards to the jquery ui dialog box, that's what gave me the idea of having a dialog box pop up upon clicking a date, I am just not sure how to implement that within a datepicker, and multiple ones at that. Do you think the bootstrap modals is more convenient for this? I've never used it before but I'm definitely going to see what I could do with that.

Comment: Also to elaborate on that quote, I'll provide an example.. Let's say the user is starting a workout plan. They can only do 10 different workouts a month, so they can only select up to 10 dates. Whichever date is the first, this will trigger the first div to appear which has the specific workout for that day and it may ask the user to input something like how many calories they burned so it will apply to only that day. The second date they select, it triggers the second div which has a different workout plan in it and the user will enter how much calories they burned on that day there...

Comment: For me, bootstrap would be the way to go, but Im admittedly biased because I use it often and am comfortable with it. Bootstrap will add a bit of bloat to your code base (but certainly not significantly so) but it comes with a TON of features out of the box like modals, accordions, carousels, tooltips , tables and too many more to list. It is easy to customize and most importantly it's built specifically to be incredibly responsive. There are also many tools that will let you play around with the features like http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: and this goes on up to 10 although it doesn't have to be 10. The 10th date is also the 10th div. Does this make better sense? I feel like maybe there will need to be a for loop that exists to traverse through the divs?

Comment: Thats really good info. How do you plan to store this data on the backend?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao The second jsfiddle I think is closer, but I think that the div's will have to be in the HTML rather than in the script since they will each contain different content that is predefined?

Comment: You can just fetch the contents based on the clicked element and append it to required div inside script..

Comment: With either approach we are able to add any combination of custom content utilizing only one popup and one display div. My vote is for a bootstrap approach because it will help make all your other layout and design work much easier as an added benefit.

Comment: Gimme a bit and Ill work up a small demo

Comment: I didn't know bootstrap had that many features, those are some really good sites I'm excited to learn more about that, thank you! Also, the form is associated with a database so each form submission will go to a specific field associated with the selected div, so they are separated by dates.

Comment: The database you are going to use, will you use something like mySql? Do you already know how to code that end of your application, or are you going to learn that part on this project?

Comment: I am using sqlite, and I have the end of it figured out, a lot of backend code is mostly python and that has been working well for the most part. I just am working on how I want the content displayed and practicing the different ways to do it and it's my first time dealing with Javascript so I'm working on a tutorial for that along with using jQuery. There is so much to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could achieve this functionality using Bootstrap. Of course you'll need to change the functionality and design as needed but this should be a fair start

**The workflow is as follows:**

- User clicks a date
- Modal is displayed with various inputs

  - Inputs are cleared when modal opens
- User enters info in the inputs
- User clicks add workout
- A span label is added to the display showing the workout number and the date selected

  - This span has data attributes set to store the date, title, and each of the values from the modal inputs
- If user clicks the "X" on the right end of the span, it is removed
- If user clicks the span label anywhere else it reopens the modal and populates the inputs with the data stored as attributes on the span
- If the user clicks add workout after loading an existing one, the new span replaces the old one instead of adding to the end of the div

#### [Here is a jsFiddle also](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/af43f1L5/4/)

```js
$(function(){
    var max_workouts = 5;
    $('#workout-datepicker').datepicker({
      startDate: "today"
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
      var cur = $('.workout-label').length;
      if (cur < max_workouts) {
        var workoutDate = e.format('mm/dd/yyyy');
        var title = 'Workout ' + (cur + 1) + ' - ' + workoutDate;
        openModal(title, workoutDate);
      }
      else{
       var $tooMany=$('#too-many');
        $tooMany.show();
        setTimeout(function(){ $tooMany.hide() }, 2000);
      }
    });
    var $workoutLabelsContainer = $('#workout-labels-container');
    $('#add-workout').click(function() {
      var $workoutModal = $('#workout-modal');
      var workoutDate = $workoutModal.data('workout-date');
      var title = $workoutModal.data('workout-title');
      var vaule1 = $('#modal-workout-value-1').val();
      var vaule2 = $('#modal-workout-value-2').val();
      var $workout = $('<span class="label label-primary workout-label col-sm-12">' + title + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right remove-workout" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>');
      var clickedLabelIndex = $workoutModal.data('crurent-label-index');
      $workout.data('workout-title', title).data('workout-date', workoutDate).data('value-1', vaule1).data('value-2', vaule2);
      if (clickedLabelIndex == -1) $workoutLabelsContainer.append($workout);
      else($('.workout-label').eq(clickedLabelIndex).replaceWith($workout))
      $workoutModal.modal('hide');
    });
    $workoutLabelsContainer.on('click', '.remove-workout', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).closest('.workout-label').remove();
    })
    $workoutLabelsContainer.on('click', '.workout-label', function() {
      var $workoutLabel = $(this);
      var workoutDate = $workoutLabel.data('workout-date');
      var title = $workoutLabel.data('workout-title');
      var value1 = $workoutLabel.data('value-1');
      var value2 = $workoutLabel.data('value-2');
      var labelIndex = $('.workout-label').index($workoutLabel);
      openModal(title, workoutDate, value1, value2, labelIndex);
    });

    function openModal(title, workoutDate, value1, value2, labelIndex) {
      var $workoutModal = $('#workout-modal');
      var $value1 = $('#modal-workout-value-1').val('');
      var $value2 = $('#modal-workout-value-2').val('');
      $workoutModal.data('workout-title', title).data('workout-date', workoutDate);
      $('#workout-modal-title').html(title);
      if (value1) $value1.val(value1);
      if (value2) $value2.val(value2);
      if (labelIndex !== 'undefined' && labelIndex > -1) $workoutModal.data('crurent-label-index', labelIndex);
      else $workoutModal.data('crurent-label-index', -1);
      $workoutModal.modal({
        show: true
      });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .workout-label {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove-workout {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#too-many{
  display:none;
}
</style>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container well" id="workout-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div id="workout-datepicker"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="workout-labels-container">
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="too-many" role="alert">Maximun reached</div>
</div>
<div id="workout-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="workout-modal-title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Some short text:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal-workout-value-1" placeholder="">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Some longer text:</label>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="modal-workout-value-2" name="textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-workout">Add workout</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That works very well, as soon as I understand it more I'm going to see if I can build off of it. It's essentially the same concept of what I am trying to do, just will need to add tweaks here and there. I will be doing a lot of reading this weekend, thank you for your help and also thank you for your suggestions, it is always nice to know of different methods and features that are possible!

Comment: @JaneDoe You are quite welcome. I have added a workflow breakdown above that may make it easier to follow. If you have any questions about the code later, feel free to ask.

Comment: So since yesterday I was able to successfully download bootstrap and the components after having a bunch of issues with the npm install, and I was practicing around with a few of the templates to get a better idea with it. For some reason, when I put your code into a file..all it displays in a webpage is a empty, light gray, horizontal div, and I can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: @JaneDoe Check out my update above. Have you placed the jQuery code inside a dom ready function like `$(function(){  ...... });` ? If not, adding that will likely solve your problem. The snippet feature here on SO adds this in the background automatically.

Comment: it hurts to admit that I left that out initially. I should've noticed that, thank you.

Comment: No worries, we've all done it, that's why it came to mind ; )

Comment: Okay so I have been trying to figure out a way to incorporate the existing divs within the code and I have been stuck because I am unsure of the way I should do it, I am pretty sure I have to get rid of value1 and value2 in your code, and I emptied the form content within the div because of the way I need to implement the different form questions.. I will edit details of the question I posted because Im running out of characters here

Comment: If you can take a look at the edit in my question and if you have any thoughts or ideas, I will be waiting for any input thank you!

Comment: @JaneDoe Where you have *"<p>I'm going to have different data applying to only this day</p>"*, can you tell me a bit about this data? What is it, will it always be the same info for workout 1 and same info for workout 2 etc.. or does the user input the data, or are you getting it from a database some context here will help

Comment: Tabs-1 content will have form questions that correlate to Tabs-1 content in the database, Tabs-2 content will have different form questions that correlate to tabs-2 content in database, and so on. The first click, will always correlate to the same questions in tabs-1, the second click will always correlate to the predefined questions in tabs-2, if they get to the fifth click, it will correlate to tabs-5 content. Therefore each click must iterate onto the next div. I don't know if this should be done through a loop as I am trying or, maybe by using something like

Comment: $.each($'#tabs'), function(i, tabs){ $('div', tabs).each(function() { }); }) but have it so that each div that is loaded into the modal correlates with the next date that is clicked. If user clicks on first date, first div content is loaded into modal, the second click results in second div content being loaded into modal.

Comment: Does each day have the same number of inputs or do they vary?

Comment: The inputs vary, it all depends on what is in the predefined divs. The form is already made up and each div correlates to a different section within the form. Would this be easier to implement if it were the same amount of inputs for each div?

Comment: Can you show me the content of the full form in a fiddle or something?

Comment: Yes, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/snwh4ug4 The form elements all correlate to a table within the DB.

Comment: I found this jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/pPyBG I basically want to apply the same concept, except that it's based on clicking dates within the calendar instead of a button that is displayed, and it would stop at the 7th div

Comment: forums.asp.net/t/1631591.aspx?How+to+iterate+through+DIVs+using+Javascript+ There are so many ways I keep finding that this can be done, I've been trying to do something like the second post in that link but applying it to the modal and I just don't know how to call on the div content and it seems impossible but I know it can be done!

Comment: Alright! I'm going to try implementing this a different way, I think doing it this way may be too complex for me since I am just beginning with javascript. I'm going to ask the user to choose a date range, if they choose 7 days, a div of 7 days will populate. They can click the first date and the first div elements will pop up, and so on. I think this will be a better way instead of figuring how to do it on calendar clicks and will result in the same concept!

Comment: @JaneDoe That sounds like a reasonable approach. Happy coding :)